# Probability in a deck of cards to have two jacks in a row

Tags: probability, combinatorics, card-games

In a deck of $36$ cards ($9$ cards per color, $4$ colors) what is the probability to have $2$ jacks (or more) that follow each other?

Comment: What is a jack defined as? What have you tried? When you say 9 cards per colour it could mean that they are all jacks.

Comment: @Alizter Apparently we may assume there are four jacks and 32 non-jacks.

Comment: Normally a deck of cards has 52 cards, since yours is cut down to 36 I have to ask: are there 4 jacks in this deck of cards?

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answers! A deck has 36 cards in switzerland, what I am used to! Sorry about that! And indeed I meant that there are 4 jacks, one per color to answer to the two first comments.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are $36\choose 4$ ways to position the jacks. There are $33\choose 4$ ways to position the jacks without adjacencies (imagine to first lay aside three neutral cards and later insert them after the first three jacks). Therefore the answer is
$$1-\frac{33\choose 4}{36\choose 4}=1-\frac{33\cdot 32\cdot 31\cdot 30}{36\cdot 35\cdot 34\cdot 33}=\frac{109}{357}. $$

Answer (score 5):

Lets count the possibilities that all jacks are separated.
Put the 32 non-jacks into a row. Now there are $\binom{33}{4} = 40920$ possibilities to choose the positions of the jacks.

The total number of possibilities is $\binom{36}{4} = 58905$.

So the result is
$$1 - \frac{40920}{58905} = \frac{109}{357} \approx 30.5\%.
$$